# JSDoc for array of array of Objects

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I wanted to represent an array of array of Object in JSDoc comment but I get syntax error in JSDoc when running lint.

This is what I am trying :-

```
{Object[][]}
```

Can someone tell me how can I write it in JSDoc comment?

Comment: Yes. It worked. If you want, u can add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the angle bracket notation for multidimensional arrays, like so:

`Object.<Array[]>`